# JUnit, Selenium and tearDown

Tags: java, junit, selenium

Such a junit :

```
    @Test
    public void testA {
//some code here...
}

    @Test
    pulic void testB {
//some code here...
}   
    @After
    public void closeBrowsers() throws Exception {
selenium.stop();
}
```

Here is the question : closeBrowsers() method called after every test method; in that case it is called twice and i got  "Wrong test finished." from JUnit. I need a junit method/annotation which will be called after all tests finised (just called once after all tests finished), is it possible ?

Also i tried to check if selenium is up or not in closeBrowsers() but no way i couldn't find
any solution.

P.S : I 've read this one : [How to close a browser on a selenium RC server which lost it's client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317844/how-to-close-a-browser-on-a-selenium-rc-server-which-lost-its-client)

but i couldn't understand the solution and also currently http://www.santiycr.com.ar/djangosite/blog/posts/2009/aug/25/close-remaining-browsers-from-selenium-rc  blog side is down

Comment: @AfterClass needs static method. 

Look at that please : 

public class xxxTest extends SeleneseTestCase {


    @Test
    public void testaaa() throws Exception {
        try {

            selenium.setSpeed("100");
            .....
       }
    }
}
   
If I use @AfterClass then  testaaa() needs to be static and in that case i can't use selenium variable...

Any solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can make your selenium variable static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your selenium variable static, initialize it in @BeforeClass static method and cleanup in @AfterClass:

```
public class ...... {

  private static Selenium selenium;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void initSelenium() {
     selenium = new DefaultSelenium(...); // or initialize it in any other way
  }

  @Test
  public void testA {...}

  @Test
  pulic void testB {...}

  @AfterClass
  public static void closeBrowsers() throws Exception { 
    selenium.stop(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: While that works if all your tests are contained in one class, that wont work if you have tests in separate class files  (and not using a Suite thereby accepting the default behavior of running all tests in project).  For that, we would need a AfterSuite annotation or a custom hack to do similar.

Comment: The question was exactly about using browser in one class, if you need to reuse the same browser for multiple tests of course you will need something else - base class for all tests, inject browser instance, etc - there are so many options

Answer (score 3):

Use the @AfterClass annotation.

http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#organize_3